# reference string-arrays in android strings.xml

Tags: android, xml, string, multidimensional-array, reference

I'd like to reference a string-array from another string-array in the strings.xml. If I try to read the string-array (named "plants") in my activity the value of every item is null.

Is there a possibility to get these values?

Here is the part of the strings.xml:

```
<string name="Orlaya_grandiflora_1">Orlaya grandiflora</string>
<string name="Orlaya_grandiflora_2">Large-Flowered Orlaya</string>
<string name="Orlaya_grandiflora_3">Apiaceae</string>
<string-array name="Orlaya_grandiflora">
    <item>@string/Orlaya_grandiflora_1</item>
    <item>@string/Orlaya_grandiflora_2</item>
    <item>@string/Orlaya_grandiflora_3</item>
</string-array>
<string-array name="plants">
    <item>@array/Ginkgo_biloba</item>
    <item>@array/Capsicum_frutescens</item>
    <item>@array/Viscum_album</item>
    <item>@array/Orlaya_grandiflora</item>
</string-array>
```

I try to access the values like this, for example:

```
String[] plantArray = resources.getStringArray(R.array.plants);

for (String plant : plantArray) {
        System.out.println("--> " + plant);
    }
```

The values of plant is in every case "null"

Anybody knows how to access the values?

Comment: what is exacly "resources"? object or else?

Comment: this was missing: Resources resources = getResources();

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should do the following :

```
  //obtain the array that refrences others array
  TypedArray plantArray=getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.plants);
  //obtain the referenced arrays
  CharSequence[] ginkoArray=plantArray.getTextArray(0);
  //...
  CharSequence[] orlayaArray=plantArray.getTextArray(3);
```

Answer (score 22):

Straight example given on: [**`Android - String Resources`**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)

[image]

Comment: this does not work with references to string-arrays, as I wrote thi side up

Comment: Why would you put string arrays inside string arrays? Is that even possible? To me it seems you can only put string resources inside the items and not string-arrays.

Comment: @eMich where i have mentioned about putting string arrays inside string arrays?

Comment: @eMich and yes i think you may right putting only string resources inside the items.

Comment: @Paresh Mayani have u any example ....to read more about string array i have search more and more on stack-over flow i have read your website many questions if u have any example link please send me thank you

Comment: i want to compare with string if or switch case i want to use ....can we use String in side of Switch in android

Comment: @PareshMayani - it should be code instead of a screen-shot. At least someone cane copy from it 

Comment: @SagarR.Kothari haha wondering how you are landed on this answer, it's a decade long answer when we were coding together :P will post the source code when we code together again :P

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Test extends ListActivity {
  String[] presidents;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ListView lstView = getListView();
    // lstView.setChoiceMode(0); //CHOICE_MODE_NONE
    // lstView.setChoiceMode(1); //CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE
    lstView.setChoiceMode(2); // CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE
    lstView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

    presidents = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.presidents_array);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, presidents));
  }

  public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View v, int position, long id) {
    parent.setItemChecked(position, parent.isItemChecked(position));

    Toast.makeText(this, "You have selected " + presidents[position],
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
};
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >



</LinearLayout>
```

strings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, MainActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">BasicViews5</string>
    <string-array name="presidents_array">
        <item>Dwight D. Eisenhower</item>
        <item>John F. Kennedy</item>
        <item>Lyndon B. Johnson</item>
        <item>Richard Nixon</item>
        <item>Gerald Ford</item>
        <item>Jimmy Carter</item>
        <item>Ronald Reagan</item>
        <item>George H. W. Bush</item>
        <item>Bill Clinton</item>
        <item>George W. Bush</item>
        <item>Barack Obama</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```